# Trouble compiling or dropping an Oracle package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was trying to compile a PL/SQL package and I got the following error:

```
ORA-04043: object SYS_PLSQL_77721_489_1 does not exist
```

After this, I can no longer recompile or drop the package.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have access to support, this looks like bug #3744836. A similar bug is described [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=423), related to pipelined functions and synonyms.

Answer (score 8):

Try to do this:

```
DROP TYPE SYS_PLSQL_77721_489_1;
DROP TYPE SYS_PLSQL_77721_DUMMY_1;
DROP PACKAGE BODY xxxx;
DROP PACKAGE xxx;
```

I've had exactly the same problem and works. Sorry @Vicent but the link you provide does not solve the problem.

Comment: That worked for me, I think. I was wondering why? The first statement tries to drop a non-existant object so fails. And what exactly is that "DUMMY" type?

Comment: This worked for us too...not sure whats really going on here though...extra points for anyone who can explain the problem!

Comment: I was able to drop using the second line (the name with "DUMMY")
 i.e. DROP TYPE SYS_PLSQL_77721_DUMMY_1;
thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

One confirmed cause of this problem is the use of pipelined functions with PL/SQL types.  It is a bug, and so ought to fixed in more recent or fully patched versions of Oracle.  A workaround would be to use SQL types instead (i.e. `create type whatever as object ...` ).

If this does not apply in your situation please edit your question to include more details.

Comment: `FETCH cur INTO rec;` only works with records and not with objects, is there any way around this?

Comment: @blaf - it depends on how you define `cur` . This seems like a different question. Ask it as such, giving enough details for us to understand your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the types as mentioned in the error message to resolve error while dropping or compiling packages.
Error :ORA-04043: object SYS_PLSQL_ B1A0D561_1132_1 does not exist
Resolution : **CREATE TYPE SYS_PLSQL_B1A0D561_1132_1;**

After that one more error came which reads
Error :ORA-04043: object SYS_PLSQL_B1A0D561_1242_1 does not exist
Resolution :**CREATE TYPE SYS_PLSQL_B1A0D561_1242_1;**

and issues resolved.

Answer (score 0):

create or replace type SYS_PLSQL_77721_489_1 as object

for all erros when you drop

try drop again and again and create type for all erros...

Comment: An answer with poor grammar is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found the object SYS_PLSQL_72104C9A_35_1 that was supposed to be missing, using PL/SQL Developer.
I suppose SQL Developer or any other IDE would work as well.
The object appeared under the types tree in the object explorer.
I fact more than one SYS_PLSQL_xxx existed.
I droped all these types and then I was able to compile my package.
So you must somehow find these mysterius invalid types and drop them.